# Sketching $y=a^x-a^{2x}, a>0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

When I need to sketch: $y=a^x-a^{2x},  a>0$, do I need to graph two functions?

One when $0<a<1$ and the other when $a>1$?

I didn't get any difference in the ascending descending intervals.

Because $y'=lna(a^x-2a^{2x})$ so y'=0
when $x=log_a0.5$ and $y''(log_a0.5)<0$
So it has a max point.
Thank you.

Comment: When you reflect the graph for $a$ in the $y$-axis, you get the graph for $1/a$.  If $a>1$, then $y$ approaches $0$ as $x\to-\infty$, but if $0<a<1$, then $y$ approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the behavior of the function differs in the cases $0<a<1$ and $a>1$. To see why, consider the function
$$
f_a(x)=a^x-a^{2x}
$$
and note that
$$
f_{1/a}(x)=f_a(-x)
$$
For instance, the graph you get for $a=1/2$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis to the graph for $a=2$.

However, after noting this, you can avoid separating the study in the two cases, because you can appeal to this symmetry.

For instance, since
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f_a(x)=-\infty
$$
for $a>1$, you already know that
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f_a(x)=-\infty
$$
for $0<a<1$.

Here's a picture for $a=3$:

[image]

and the corresponding picture for $a=1/3$:

[image]

As you correctly point out, the maximum of $f_a$ is at $-\log_a2$, which is positive for $0<a<1$ and negative for $a>1$. The symmetry above explains it.

Comment: I understand:) BTW, what program did you use here for the sketches?

Comment: @Don That's Grapher, which comes for free with Mac OS X

Comment: Another advantage for Mac..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $ a^x =u $ giving $ y= u -u^2 = u ( u-1).$

$ y>0 $ for $ 0 < u < 1$ and $ <0$ outside this interval. As log is negative for real quantities $ < 1 ,$ two behaviours are expected.